# I have transformed my cyclic variables into sin-cos variables; will I need further normalization/standardization?

Tags: machine-learning, python, regression, preprocessing

I have a dataset where there are both numerical, categorical and cyclic(month-quarter) variables.

I will run a regression model, but I may also use Random Forest, XGBoost etc. So I will preprocess my data. During preprocessing stage, I transformed Cyclic variables into sin-cos representation. Both columns are now scattered between -1 and 1.

I will one-hot-encode the categorical variables, this is for sure.

But I have some questions for numerical transformations:

1) In general, can I transform some of the columns by standardization and some of the columns by normalization? Or should I choose a method and apply for all numerical columns?

2) It is also similar to 1. Now I have sin-cos columns, already transformed from a cyclic variable.

Should I further apply numerical transformation to this column, for example If I normalize all numeric variables between 0-1, will I apply this transformation also sin-cos columns?

May be the best way is normalizing every numerical column between -1 and 1?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but why do you want to normalise when you use xgb, lgbm?

Comment: You may be right for boosting algorithms, I assumed I would need normalization which may not be true. But I will use various algorithms, and I want to learn the answers of questions independent from the algorithm I use.

Comment: This was asked three years ago. What did you learn about this?